# Javascript: Allow Only Values less than input initial value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

on my form, I have many text input fields with pre-filled decimal values, the user can edit the values before submitting the form.

I was wondering if there is anyway using javascript/jquery, to make each input allow only values less than its initial value.

I find it quite challenging, so I thought about posting it here.
Thank you guys

Comment: Is it for updating single element?

Comment: i'm afraid i don't understand what you mean by updating single element ;/

Comment: You can't validate on the client side. I could forge a form and submit it; bypassing any client side checking. You must do any serious validation on the server-side. When you're just messing around, this isn't a huge concern; just know that you can't trust data coming from a client.

Comment: Definitely, I will validate the data on the server side, but I'd like to know if there anyway I can add an extra layer on the client side.

Comment: What I mean is do you want to get the old values and change it to new values and then validate that?

Comment: You can write something that will validate the form before it goes to the sever and alerts or informs the user that it has to the value need to be less than said amount.

Comment: @andremcgruder that(s exactly what I'm looking for :D

Comment: @aldrin27 old values are already pre-filled for each input. i want to make only editing to less values possible

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you share your code HTML/Javascript and other dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery Validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)'s [max method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/max-method/).

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Makes "field" required and 23 or smaller.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">

</head>
<body>
<form id="myform">
<label for="field">Required, maximum value 23: </label>
<input type="text" class="left" id="field" name="field">
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Validate!">
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      max: $('your_input_selector').val()
    }
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @DucFilan, in my case I'm using input arrays.. how can I adapt the selector the work with that ?

Comment: It doesn't depend on selector or not, if you can pass the value to the rules, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```js
var initialValue = $("#myTextbox1").val()
$("#myTextbox1").on("input", function() {
    if($("#myTextbox1").val() > initialValue) {
        $("#myTextbox1").val(initialValue);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myTextbox1" type="text" value="5"/>
```

Comment: You should convert the values to numbers before comparing them.

Comment: And if you are using the input in a form you need to preventDefault on the event to cancel out the default form action.

Answer (score 0):

This solution converts the input into a number, prevents default form action, checks if the input value is a number and if not it alerts the user and resets the default input value, checks to see if the new value is less the the original and if it is not it resets the input to the original value.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
    <input type="text" id="myValue" value="5" />
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="validate" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var origVal = $('#myValue').val();

$('#myButton').on('click', function(e) {
        var getVal = Number($('#myValue').val());
        e.preventDefault();

        if (isNaN(getVal) === true) {
            alert('The input value has to be a number.');
            $('#myValue').val(origVal);
        }

        if (getVal > origVal) {
            alert('The input value has to be less than the original value of ' + origVal);
            $('#myValue').val(origVal);
        }
    });
```